# Quartz scheduler-CalendarTrigger

Tags: java, triggers, quartz-scheduler

I am using CalendarTriggerImpl for triggering my job on every 3 days.My start time is 2012-12-10 15:00:00 and end time is 2013-12-10.But when I execute my scheduler on 2012-12-11 11:00:00,the job will execute.How to solve this issue.I am not using cron trigger because it will reset in every month.So please help me to trigger my job on 2012-12-10 15:00:00, 2012-12-13 15:00:00, 2012-12-16 15:00:00 and so on even if I execute my scheduler on any date.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you start the scheduler after the job should execute so it find that job as misfired. Try to look at misfire instruction used in your trigger.